# Transform tree category array to one line

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have got an array (category tree)

```
[category_name_en] => en
[category_name_ru] => ru
[id_category] => 86314
[children] => Array
    (
        [category_name_en] => en 2
        [category_name_ru] => ru 2
        [id_category] => 86296
    )
```

this I got from database - recursion

I'm trying to get such output

```
[category_en] => en > en2;
[category_ru] => ru > ru2;
```

In thise example array have two levels but it can be more levels... please give me an idea or help.

Comment: What does `en > en2` represent?  For example, if `en = 1` and `en2 = 2` do you want `[category_en] => false`?

Comment: simple text. I just want to make function which will output "text > text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like this to get you started:

```
function flattenChildren(array $array, $key) {
    $chain = !empty($array['children']) ? flattenChildren($array['children'], $key) : array();
    array_unshift($chain, $array[$key]);
    return $chain;
}

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo join(' > ', flattenChildren($category, 'category_name_en')), "\n";
}
```